# Fortran MPI - Can't get existing codebase working on new server

Tags: compiler-errors, fortran, mpi, fortran90

I'm attempting to compile and run a fortran script on a new server(works on my old).  If I run via gfortran; it runs happily. If I run via mpif90; I get this error...

```
wom@rl-womserv:~/$ mpif90 nrutil.f90 minimization.f90 main.f90 -O3 -o mpi.exe; mpiexec -n 2 ./mpi.exe
./mpi.exe: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/libmpi_f77.so.1: undefined symbol: opal_uses_threads
./mpi.exe: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/libmpi_f77.so.1: undefined symbol: opal_uses_threads
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
mpiexec noticed that the job aborted, but has no info as to the process
that caused that situation.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I A:B'd the packages installed on my slow(working Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS, gfortran and mpif90) and fast new(Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS, working gfortran, broken mpif90) and don't really see any differences.

Any pointers where I should look would greatly be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I had my library paths wrong.

export PATH="$PATH:/opt/openmpi-1.8/bin"
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/opt/openmpi-1.8/lib"

in my profile and all is well.  Thanks for the look.. :)

-Chris

Answer (score 2):

If you moved to a new system, it's possible that you've moved from one implementation of MPI to another.

One thing that's easy to forget about MPI is that it's a standard, not a library. You originally compiled your code with Open MPI (which is apparent from its reference to `opal`), but you might have moved to a system that's using MPICH (or something else like Intel MPI).

It's not a problem to move your code back and forth since (as long as you're only using standard MPI functions and not extensions) it should be portable, but if you're going between Open MPI and MPICH, you'll have to recompile your code on the new machine.

FYI: for some implementations, this is no longer true per the [MPICH ABI Compatibility Initiative](http://www.mpich.org/abi/).

Comment: Notice the first part of his command line, `mpif90 nrutil.f90 minimization.f90 main.f90 -O3 -o mpi.exe`. He recompiles everything.

Comment: Fair enough. In that case, it's probably an installation problem.